# How to listen to incoming request when configuring vue-socket.io globally in VueJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, vue.js, socket.io, global

I would like to know how to listen to an incoming request from a server when configuring vue-socket.io globally in VueJS.

I followed [vue-socket.io - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io) to set up vue-socket.io globally as follows:
[configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4N4v.png)

I think the configuration works because it is possible to pass data from a client to a server.
However, on the client-side, I cannot listen to data from the server.

I tried using *socket option*, *this.$socket.on*, *this.$socket.subscribe*, *this.sockets.subscribe*, and the results are below:

*Case*: this.$socket.on
  result: doesn't run
[case: this.$socket.on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgmGF.png)

*Case*: socket option
  result: doesn't run
[case: socket option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdLDF.png)

*Case*: this.$socket.subscribe & this.sockets.subscribe
  result: TypeError: this.$socket.subscribe is not a function

I have attached [server-side code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND7rh.png) to clarify my problem.

I would be grateful if you could help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think they explane it here this.$socket, how you can access your socket connection via `this.$socket`, and such

Comment: One thing, if you want to listen an event in a component, use `this.$socket.on(...)` stuff in your created or mounted lifecycles not in methods

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried using "this.$socket.on(...)" in created and mounted lifecycles, however, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Aight, do you actually send that event from your server?

Comment: I gave up setting it up globally, and I worked well by importing the socket.io-client in App.vue. As for your question, I am sure that I send the event from the server.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to change `import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io'` to `import VueSocketIOExt from 'vue-socket.io-extended'` and all off cases will work

difference is  `this.$socket.emit('changed')` (vue-socket.io version) to  `this.$socket.client.emit('changed')` (vue-socket.io-extended version)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io-extended